# How can I create many modals dynamically with ngFor Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm getting an array of objects. In every object, one of the values is a link of a document or an image, then I have to show in a modal that file or image in a frame or something like that. The only way that I can do it manually was like this:

```
<object data="https://.../sample.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="100%"
        height="500px">
```

Then, I tried to set the URL in the **data** of the HTML `<object>` to show it in just one modal. 
But I can`t do it, so the last idea was to make one modal for each file, but I can´t too.

Here is my current code for the dynamic modals.

```
<tr *ngFor="let row of rows">
  <td>
    <button data-toggle="modal" attr.data-target="modal-{{row.id}}">
      Documento
    </button>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Here is the modal.

```
<div *ngFor="let row of rows">
    <div class="modal fade" attr.id="modal-{{row.id}}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Vista previa documento</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <object attr.data="{{row.document}}" type="application/pdf" 
                            width="100%" height="500px">
                    </object>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it doesn`t work.

I`ve tried both ideas, but no one works. I'm kind of knew it Angular, so I'm trying to understand all this. Thanks!

Comment: any error message? maybe try    attr.data="row.document"    w/o the handlebars

Comment: No, the problem here is that I can't show each modal. It didn´t work the data target reference to the modal. I can inspect the code, and the code it's ok, the file link is there, but I can't see the modal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating one modal per document, I would create one single modal and change its content based on which button I click:

For the button:

```html
<button *ngFor="let row of rows" (click)="setSelectedRow(row)">
    Documento {{row.id}}
</button>
```

For the modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="single-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Vista previa documento {{selectedRow?.id}}</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fal fa-times"></i></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <iframe *ngIf="selectedRow"
                        [src]="selectedRow.document"
                        width="100%" height="500px">
                </iframe>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subir</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
  setSelectedRow(row: any) {
    this.selectedRow = row;
    $('#single-modal').modal("show");
  }
```

See a working [StackBlitz here](https://angular-28gylq.stackblitz.io/).

You can also do it with an `<object>`, likely you'll need a different method from the [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer) (try the `sanitize` method).

Comment: Thank you so much!, I did the Sanitize thing and solve my problem. Now my problem is "Carga denegada por X-Frame-Options: “DENY”". But thanks, now I can focus in another problem.